# textmate does not save commit message

Tags: macos, git, osx-mountain-lion, textmate

I'm installing git on a new Mac mini with textmate2 and git 1.8.3.2.
It works quite fine, but when I use `gca` (`git commit -v -a`) it doesn't act as before. 
It opens textmate2 so I can type my commit message, but when I save and close it doesn't jump back to terminal as before. Terminal shows the error

> Aborting commit due to empty commit message.

Anybody have an idea what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried searching any other questions that deal with editor problems in Git, like with vim or notepad++?

Answer (score 4):

This happens, if the environment variables $EDITOR and/or $VISUAL are not set correctly. You need to add the -w flag to mate, otherwise git does not wait for Textmate to close the file and assumes your message is ready the moment your editor opens - before you even start typing.

**Wrong:**

export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/mate"

**Right:**

export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/mate -w"